# oracle DELETE prepared statement

Tags: java

I need your help please! I have a problem at the level of the delete it goes very well at the console but at the level in the database no changes. Thanks for you help

```
public void b2_action() {
   try {
           String req ="DELETE from EMPLOYEES where 'FIRST_NAME' = (?)";
           conn = macon.getConnection();
           PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(req);
           String a= text.getValue().toString();
           System.out.println(a);
           ps.setString(1,a);
           ps.executeUpdate();
           System.out.println("okkkkkkkkkkkkkkk");
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

[delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRELz.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haonC.png)

Comment: Why did you put quotes around a column name?  Please refer to the SQL language reference for the dialect of SQL that you are using; i.e. the only in your DB documentation.

Comment: Where do you commit the transaction ?

Comment: I guess, you're not committing the transaction because I can't see in your provided code.

Comment: Could you accept an answer if your issue is solved?

Answer (score 2):

The query must be:

```
String req ="DELETE from EMPLOYEES where FIRST_NAME = ?";
```

note the remotion of the single quotes... **' '**

Comment: Quotes not needed for substituted parameters.

Comment: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (HR.LOC_C_ID_FK) violated - child record found

Comment: At least now your query trying to do more serious changes :)

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes
 in your query:

- you don't need to put `FIRST_NAME` between quotes
- you don't need parenthesis between your `?`

```
String req = "DELETE from EMPLOYEES where FIRST_NAME = ?";
```

Comment: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (HR.LOC_C_ID_FK) violated - child record found